# Redirect to URL (via header) vs. copying pasting URL in browser

Tags: php, redirect, token, referer

Noticed that token information when sent to a 3rd party service in the in format "https://domaindotcom/login/token/blah.blah.blah.blah" works fine when copying and pasting it into the browser.

Now, when the same token is sent from a webpage sitting on an internal website via a PHP redirect (using the header function) we get issues. The redirect executes, the token triggers the event with the vendor, but it fails to finalize.
The page sits on a web server which is NOT accessible by the world.

Differences perhaps in what information gets sent out via these two methods?

Would a browser send more info when a PHP script is triggered on it such as referer?

Perhaps referer information received via the PHP header redirect function, and the vendor attempts to ping back (if their server detects a referer), but since the server is not accessible it may be flagged and process killed?

Would appreciate thoughts and ideas on what may be happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has to do with their cookie settings. Specifically, if the cookie setting of the domain you are redirecting to contains `SameSite=strict`, the first request after a redirect from another domain will not include cookies.

Comment: So the not being able to set the cookie?

Since the server (where the webpage which does the redirect) is not being accessible by the world, where would they attempt to set the cookie to?

When pasting the token in the URL, the info is sent, cookie is set and they are good with it and proceed to process that? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = window.location.href;
var stringWithNumbers = str;

var n = 1;

console.log(str);
var changedString = stringWithNumbers.replace(/\/(\w+)/ig,v => n++ == 4 ? "ltfgt" : v);
```

console.log(changedString);

```
var st = changedString.split('ltfgt')[0];
console.log(st)


var str2 = "/Videos/folder/pencil.html";
var res = st.concat(str2);
console.log(res);

window.location.href=res;
var rplc= st.replace("ltfgt","/Videos/folder/pencil.html");
console.log(rplc);
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?